# How to change the project name property in the subproject list in Gradle after initialisation?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I would like to know if it was possible to modify the project name property in the `subprojects` list in Gradle, after the build?

I'll try to explain myself a little bit better. In Gradle, you specify the name of your projects in a `settings` file that is included during initialization.

However, for some reasaon I need to change to order in which the projects are processed at "runtime".

ex : `println $subprojects will show [project : 'a', project : 'b', project : 'c']`

I have already done the sorting in a different list but it would be a bit cleaner and more maintainable if I could modify the program in order for the `subprojects` list to match my sorted list.

Comment: _"For some reason"_ ... Can you explain the reason?

Comment: The projects are git repos, and the program is materialized by a GUI. The user's actions will determine wether the repos need to be rebased, merged or if nothing needs to happen. The repos where actions are going to be done need to be dealt with last because there is a possibility that they could disrupt (stall) the program, which processes everything sequentially.